# How do I find a page in python?

Tags: python

What i'm trying to do is find a specific page in python, By that I mean like: for example, if the exists it will output that it does, If it doesn't then it won't. I know that but the problem is, what's the function to find a page of a website? Like. I want to find /test/ and if it doesn't exist it will say "/test/ does not exist on the website: test.com"

What do I have to do?

Comment: what have you tried? hint: try to download the page and check if it succeeded.

Comment: I don't want it to download the page, I just want it to `try:` to find the page in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the page. Example using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://google.com/test')
>>> response.status_code
404
>>> if response.status_code == 404:
...     print "/test/ does not exist on the website: google.com"
... 
/test/ does not exist on the website: google.com
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a library like `requests`, you can simply try the url. If it returns a 404, then the page does not exist.

E.g.

```
 r = requests.get('http://test.com/test')
 if r.status_code == 404:
     print "/test/ does not exist on the website: test.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use built in urllib module

```
from urllib import urlopen

response = urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993222/how-do-i-find-a-page-in-python')

if response.getcode() == 200:
    print("page exists")
elif response.getcode() == 404:
    print("page does not exist")
```